# ¿Como enviar datos desde un servicio a una actividad principal o MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

Resulta que tengo una variable tipo int en mi Mainactivity, la envio constantemente a mi servicio que es un reproductor de musica, esta variable me permite cambiar el orden de las canciones, al cambiarlas en el servicio necesito que tambien se actualicen en mi Mainactivity para que tanto mi notificacion(servicio) como mis controles principales(MainActivity) se sincronicen y no se repitan las canciones, pero no se como hacerlo

Comment: Deberías poner lo que has intentado o al menos la idea que llevas (si tienes alguna). Yo te recomendaría pensar en eventos porque de primeras, parece lo mejor para lo que preguntas

Comment: Ps ideas, intente con Broadcast y no me funciono

Comment: Repito, deberías poner lo que has intentado, hasta ahora no has puesto nada de código y por lo tanto, parece que no hayas intentado nada y quieres que te resolvamos el problema.

Comment: Perdona me no se me ocurre nada

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días Felipe.

Una opción que tienes es declarar la variable int como pública y estática para poder acceder desde otra clase (en este caso un servicio) y así actualizarla.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static int randomCode;
}
```

Luego para poder acceder a ella desde el servicio:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    ...
    int serviceRandomCode; // Variable de control aleatorio del servicio
    MainActivity.randomCode = serviceRandomCode;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Pense en eso pero necesito enviar esta variable u otras